# jquery nestable how to prevent/reject a drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Anyone know how to prevent an item from being dropped into the root of a list.  Or even more specifically - how can I limit it to to only allow dropped items on the "dd-handle" class.

I tried fiddled with jquery.nestable.js plugin file in the dragStop method.  I can intercept drops to the root here, but doesn't cleanly prevent the action.

```
dragStop: function(e)
{
        var thePlace = this.pointEl.closest('.' + this.options.rootClass);
        if(thePlace.length < 1) {
            e.preventDefault;
            return false;
        }

 ...

}
```

Anyone know of a more effective / sanctioned way to prevent dropping onto specific targets?

Answer (score 0):

go to the jquery.nestable.js file and find for **onDragStart** and add in curly braces like below :

onDragStart: function(l, e, p) {event.preventDefault();return false;},

Hurray done!